# How to specify two generic parameters for an extension method in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, extension-methods

I'm trying to write an extension method with following signature

```
public static D GetModelFor<S, D>(this S source) 
            where S : BusinessBase
```

I have following class

```
public class Order : BusinessBase
```

I want to be able to call the extension method on an instance of Order class as

```
Order o = new Order();
SomeOtherClass s = o.GetModelFor<SomeOtherClass>();
```

But this does not work. The C# compiler is asking me to specify both the types of S and D. In this case Order and SomeOtherClass. Am I doing anything wrong here?

======== More Details of the internal implementation =========

```
    public static D GetModelFor<S, D>(this S source) 
        where D : IMappingProvider, new()
    {
        D d = new D();
        d.CreateMap();
        return Mapper.Map<S, D>(source);
    }
```

Here `IMappingProvider` is an interface which gives a class a way to register the maps for auto-mapper. As you can see, I need type `S` to use in `Mapper.Map<>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason for not just doing

```
public static T GetModelFor<T>(this BusinessBase source)
```

?

Comment: Yeah. I want GetModelFor method to return an object of type other than T.

Comment: @Suhas: Could you show some of your planned implementation, then? I thought the parameter in your `GetModelFor<SomeOtherClass>` example was meant to be `D`, which matches my line here.

Comment: You are right, that is `D`. But I also need to specify `S` so that `GetModelFor<SomeOtherClass>` becomes an extension method on type `S`

Comment: @Suhas: I still don't see why you can't do it like I suggested. How about posting an example with two type arguments and what you would actually have inside the method?

Comment: I understand your point now. I have added the implementation details of `GetModelFor` in the original question above. I need to specify type `S` for auto-mapper.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I doing anything wrong here?

Yes - if you specify any type parameters, you must specify them all.

```
Order o = new Order();
SomeOtherClass s = o.GetModelFor<Order, SomeOtherClass>();
SomeOtherClass s2 = o.GetModelFor<BusinessBase, SomeOtherClass>();
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement an extension method so as to get rid of need to specify the first parameter.